# Escrever a média dos números digitados, se eles forem pares. Terminar a leitura quando o usuário digitar zero(0)

Tags: java, while

Ex) Escreva um algoritmo que calcule a média dos números digitados pelo usuário, se eles forem pares. Termine a leitura se o usuário digitar zero.

Fiz assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
    int numero = x.nextInt();

    while(numero < 0 | numero > 0){
        System.out.println("Digite outro número");

    /*
    *imagino que eu tenha que usar outra variável, mas isso prejudicaria
    *no inicio do meu while, que diz q a variável número não pode ser 0.
    */
        numero = x.nextInt();

    /*
     *existe maneira de guardar vários valores em uma mesma variável?(imagino 
     *que seja inviável).
     */
```

Alguém poderia me mostrar como fica resolvido o algoritmo usando while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível solução para seu problema:

```
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
    int numero = x.nextInt();
    int somatorio = numero;
    int qnt = 1;
    while (numero != 0) {
        System.out.println("Digite outro número");
        numero = x.nextInt();
        if (numero != 0) {
            if(numero%2==0){
                somatorio += numero;
                qnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Media = "+(somatorio/qnt));
```

Com isso a media será apenas dos números pares digitados.

Uma segunda opção :

```
   Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
   int numero = 0;
   int somatorio = 0;
   int qnt = 0;
   do {
        System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
        numero = x.nextInt();
        if (numero != 0) {
            if (numero % 2 == 0) {
                somatorio += numero;
                qnt++;
            }
         }
     } while (numero != 0);
     if (qnt != 0)
         System.out.println("Media = " + (somatorio / qnt));
     else
         System.out.println("Nenhum numero par digitado");
```

Comment: do jeito que tava antes da edição até que deu certo, o único problema é que a média não tava saindo com o resultado correto.
agora depois de editado ele ta fazendo a média dos dois últimos números digitados.
Fiz assim como você explicou:
 while(numero != 0){
  System.out.println("Digite outro número");
  numero = x.nextDouble();
  somatorio += numero;
  qnt++;
 }  
 System.out.println("Media ="+(somatorio/qnt));  
 }
    }
porém quando faço por exemplo, 10, 8, 6, 0. ao invés da média sair 8 que seria o certo, sai 4.666. De qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Comment: deu certo, obrigadow!!!

Comment: só ta rolando um probleminha, ele ta ignorando o primeiro valor fornecido, na hora de calcular a média.

Comment: Ajustei, agora esta funcionando

Comment: perfeito, obrigadão, agora vou estudar teu código kkk. abraço

Comment: Unico problema é se o primeiro numero for impar ou zero.

Comment: Realizei outra resposta com uma solução que atende todas as opções

Comment: se for zero ele para o programa, mas isso tá certo, único problema mesmo é quando o primeiro é ímpar q a média da errada, mas não pega nada, valeu a força ai man!

Comment: Precisando estamos a disposição =)